# Multiple Join Searching in Database

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I want to fetch the records from database in my ongoing project.

I have 5 Tables; Everyone make profile which is saved in starting four tables then define partner profile. I want to to fetch all the partner name which meets profile.

This is my tables structure:

```
Basic Info (reg_id, name, gender, dob, martial_status)
Education (id,reg_id,education,college)
Location (id,reg_id,country,state, city)
Other_details (id,reg_id,height, weight)
Partner (id, reg_id, gender, dob, education, college, country, state, city, height, weight,martial_status) [ This is the Main Table]..
```

So far I tried this but no luck:

```
SELECT `basic_info`.`reg_id`,
       `basic_information`.`dob`,
       `other_detail`.`height`,
       `location`.`city`,
       `education`.`education` 
FROM `basic_information`
INNER JOIN(
          SELECT * 
          FROM `patner` 
          WHERE `patner`.`reg_id`='shi01') `patner` 
      ON `basic_information`.`martial_status`=`partner`.`martial_status` 
      AND `basic_information`.`reg_id`!='shi01'
INNER JOIN `education` 
      ON `patner`.`education`=`education`.`education` 
      AND `patner`.`education`=`education`.`education`
INNER JOIN `location` 
      ON `patner`.`city`=`location`.`city`
INNER JOIN `other_detail` 
      ON `patner`.`bodytype`=`other_detail`.`body_type` 
      AND `patner`.`skin`=`other_detail`.`skin` 
      AND `patner`.`height1` <=  `other_detail`.`height` 
GROUP BY `basic_information`.`reg_id`;
```

Comment: please provide the table definition. What are the primary and foreign keys in your tables. ?

Comment: in First table Reg_id is PK..
In Rest it is FK..

Answer (score 0):

You did some mistakes in writing join conditions. I have tried to fix it. Try this, It should work;

```
 SELECT BI.reg_id, BI.name
 FROM basic_info BI
 INNER JOIN
     Education E ON BI.reg_id = E.reg_id
 INNER JOIN
     Location L ON BI.reg_id = L.reg_id
 INNER JOIN
     Other_details OD ON BI.reg_id = OD.reg_id
 INNER JOIN
     (Select reg_id, martial_status, height, education, city FROM Partner where reg_id = 'Your_ID') P 
     ON BI.reg_id = P.reg_id
 WHERE
    BI.marital_status = P.marital_Status
    AND E.Education = P.Education
    AND L.city = P.City
    AND OD.height <= P.Height
    AND BI.reg_id <> 'Your_ID';
```